# AlertDialog not be shown when receiving sms

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I work on an app this sending a sms and showing the received sms as an `AlertDialog` but AlertDialog Not be shown when receiving SMS 
here is the Code Of my project:

MainActivity:

```
package com.am7.masirinfo;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



TextView tv;
SharedPreferences prefs;
Button sendBtn;   
EditText txtphoneNo;   
EditText txtMessage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });




    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8A0441")));
    bar.show();
    bar.setIcon(R.drawable.bar);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);







    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
    tx.setTypeface(custom_font);

    TextView tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Typeface custom_font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/gmail.ttf");
    tx1.setTypeface(custom_font1);
    TextView tx2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
    tx2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    TextView tx3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tx4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);





     sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);      
     txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);      
     txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
      sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
          public void onClick(View view) {            
              sendSMSMessage();         
              }      
          });
   }   protected void sendSMSMessage() {      
       Log.i("Send SMS", "");
          String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();      
      String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
      try {         SmsManager smsManager =
SmsManager.getDefault();         
      smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);         
      AlertDialog ad1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
        ad1.setCancelable(false); 
        // This blocks the 'BACK' button 
        ad1.setMessage("با موفقیت ارسال شد");
        ad1.setTitle("انجام شد");
        ad1.setButton("باش", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override    
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {        
                dialog.dismiss();                        
                } 
            }); 
        ad1.show();
        ad1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);    
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {   
          AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
        ad.setCancelable(false); 
        // This blocks the 'BACK' button 
        ad.setMessage("متاسفانه ارسال نشد مجددا تلاش کنید.");
        ad.setTitle("خطایی رخ داد!");
        ad.setButton("خب", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override    
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {        
                dialog.dismiss();                        
                } 
            }); 
        ad.show();
        ad.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);      
          e.printStackTrace();



      }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

        }
```

and this is the SmsReceiver.java :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {        
// Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if 
            (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + phoneNumber + "; message: " + message);
                    if 
                    (TextUtils.equals(currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress(), "+981000141")) {                    
                     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                     builder.setTitle("اطلاعات ریافت شد!");
                     builder.setMessage(message);
                     builder.setPositiveButton("HEY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                     {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                     builder.show();
                        }



                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }

    private CharSequence contains(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

Main_layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sms_label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSMS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="����: 0711 0511 ���� ����� �� ����"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:background="@drawable/abstract_877"
    android:text="@string/send_sms_label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPhoneNo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:text="+981000141"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="����� �� ���� ��� ���� � Ӂ� �� �� � ����� �� ��� ���� �� ���� ������."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#00BD39" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:text="AM7group@gmail.com" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="www.iran141.ir"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="+981000141"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="339dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/exitbtn" />
```

Logcat:

```
05-26 20:16:53.509: I/SmsReceiver(31910): senderNum: +981000141; message: عجبا
05-26 20:16:53.529: I/SmsReceiver(31356): senderNum: +981000141; message: عجبا
05-26 20:16:53.639: E/SmsReceiver(31356): Exception  smsReceiverandroid.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

After along conversation with @faizal I changed the main activity but I got 2 errors once in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



TextView tv;
SharedPreferences prefs;
Button sendBtn;   
EditText txtphoneNo;   
EditText txtMessage;
SmsReceiver BR_smsreceiver = null;








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BR_smsreceiver = new SmsReceiver();
    BR_smsreceiver.setActivityHandler(this);
    IntentFilter fltr_smsreceived = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(BR_smsreceiver, fltr_smsreceived);

    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });




    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8A0441")));
    bar.show();
    bar.setIcon(R.drawable.bar);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


    public void showAlert(string message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);                 
        builder.setTitle(" !");                 
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("HEY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }







    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
    tx.setTypeface(custom_font);

    TextView tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Typeface custom_font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/gmail.ttf");
    tx1.setTypeface(custom_font1);
    TextView tx2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
    tx2.setTypeface(custom_font);
    TextView tx3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tx4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);





     sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);      
     txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);      
     txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
      sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
          public void onClick(View view) {            
              sendSMSMessage();         
              }      
          });
   }   protected void sendSMSMessage() {      
       Log.i("Send SMS", "");
          String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();      
      String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
      try {         SmsManager smsManager =
SmsManager.getDefault();         
      smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);         
      AlertDialog ad1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
        ad1.setCancelable(false); 
        // This blocks the 'BACK' button 
        ad1.setMessage("�� ������ ����� ��");
        ad1.setTitle("����� ��");
        ad1.setButton("���", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override    
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {        
                dialog.dismiss();                        
                } 
            }); 
        ad1.show();
        ad1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);    
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {   
          AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
        ad.setCancelable(false); 
        // This blocks the 'BACK' button 
        ad.setMessage("�������� ����� ��� ����� ���� ����.");
        ad.setTitle("����� �� ���!");
        ad.setButton("��", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override    
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {        
                dialog.dismiss();                        
                } 
            }); 
        ad.show();
        ad.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);      
          e.printStackTrace();



      }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

The Error is in public void method.
And twice error is in SmsReceiver but this problem is for this problem! 
Here you are @faizal

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the layout file also?

Comment: Did you register the receiver in the manifest?

Comment: @faizal editted for you!

Comment: @user184994 yes I registered it!

Comment: @user184994 dear I have 3 activity: 1-splashScreen 2-MainActivity 3-SmsReceiver I registered it under the first activity(SplashScreen) can you help me?

Comment: Are you getting any error or is it just a logic problem? Have you checked the value of currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress() ? Is it "+981000141"?

Comment: @faizal haven't any error. Dear "+981000141" is a filter that shows only receiving sms from this number but dont show alert dialog when receiving sms from this number. Can you say me how to delete this and show Alertdialog for all numbers? Thanks!

Comment: Does your IF condition get satisfied? If you put a Log statement inside the IF block, does it print to Logcat? I am just trying to figure out if your control gets into the IF block at all.

Comment: @faizal I'm biginer :D not understood

Comment: The Log.i statement in your code will print to Android's logging mechanism called Logcat. It usually opens up automatically in Eclipse, when you run an Android app from Eclipse on your connected phone. If it does not show up, you can open it maually by going to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Logcat. It will help you determine whether control flow is going to your sms receiver or not.

Comment: @faizal in the logcat some lines: RECEIVER: PAKAGAGE_REPLACED : com.am7.masirinfo if you want copy it for you akhi

Comment: Type "tag:SmsReceiver" in the box at the top of the logcat window to filter for only your specific log statements. And choose "verbose" in the dropdown next to it. Then press the "Clear Log" button so that you don't get confused with older logs. Now receive an sms from any number and then check the entries in logcat. If you see any entries, it means your sms receiver is working. Share those lines in your question to help you further.

Comment: @faizal oh bro!!!!  See here!!!! Some errors. But I don't understand what that sey! Help me bro!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the context being supplied to the onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver is an application context(as opposed to activity context), which cannot be used to show a dialog box apparently. So you need to show the dialog in your running activity instead of in the broadcast receiver.

1. In your SmsReceiver class, create a function to receive the main activity class object :

   ```
   MainActivity act = null;
   void setActivityHandler(MainActivity act)
   {
   this.act=act;
   }
   ```
2. Register the broadcast receiver in the main activity(instead of in the splash screen) and call setActivityHandler(). So you will have the following lines in your main activity :

   ```
   SmsReceiver BR_smsreceiver = null;

   onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
   ....
   BR_smsreceiver = new SmsReceiver();
   BR_smsreceiver.setActivityHandler(this);
   IntentFilter fltr_smsreceived = new     
   IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
   registerReceiver(BR_smsreceiver, fltr_smsreceived);
   ....
   }
   ```
3. In your SmsReceiver class, remove all the AlertDialog builder lines and replace it with

   ```
   act.showAlert(message);
   ```
4. In your main activity class, create the showAlert() :

   ```
   public void showAlert(String message){
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("اطلاعات ریافت شد!");
                    builder.setMessage(message);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("HEY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {

                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       }
                   });
                    builder.show();
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh, Very Very Thanks to my bro faizal <3

Comment: Mr. I do it. Excuse me but I saw 2 errors in java file! How to resole? 1-in mainActivity: public void showAlert (string... Error: void is an invalid type for the variable showAlert then 2-smsReceiver.java : act.showAlert(message... The method showAlert(string) is undefined for the type MainActivity can you help me?

Comment: Upload your mainActivity class publicly somewhere like Dropbox and share the link. I'll take a look.

Comment: Excuse me Different by if copy the text of MainActivity and put this in this place?

Comment: Pasting code in comments is really messy, as all formatting is lost. Also there is a character limit in comments. Maybe you can add an edit section in your question and paste it there.

Comment: You have defined showAlert() inside onCreate(). It needs needs to be outside. You can move it to just before "protected void sendSMSMessage().."

Comment: It would be better if a new question is posted for every error that you face, with the code and error message and any steps that you have taken to debug. Long conversations in comments is discouraged by SO policy.

Comment: Oh faizal I have succfulled you Are best@-}--

Comment: Glad I could help. If you gain more reputation on SO, you will have access to the chat module, which would be more helpful in situations like this.